# Response of Http Api call promise is undefined - Angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-promise

I have created an api in WebAPI as below.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get() {

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Hello World"), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
```

I am trying to call it from Angular as below

**Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {

     constructor(private http:Http){}

     GetHttpData(){

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:54037/api/home')
        .map((res:Response)=>res.json());
     }
```

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  { 

  data2: String;
  constructor(private s: DemoService){} 

  ngOnInit(){

    this.s.GetHttpData().subscribe(data=>this.data2=data);
    console.log("Http call  completed: "+this.data2);

}
```

**On running the application, I get output:**

Http call  completed: undefined

Can someone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See the duplicates, that is expected behavior with your code. Put the `console.log` statement *inside* the `subscribe` callback. Read through the suggested duplicates so you understand the fundamentals of asynchronous code in javascript/typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `console.log` inside the data function.

Could you try like this.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  { 

  data2: String;
  constructor(private s: DemoService){} 

  ngOnInit(){

    this.s.GetHttpData().subscribe(data=>{
        this.data2=data;
        console.log("Http call  completed: "+this.data2)
    });

}
```

Comment: You should read up on what to do with duplicate questions... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @AJT_82 While I'm answering there is no duplicate flag may be some network issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to work with a simple promise here.

**In Service.ts (DemoService)**

```
 GetHttpData() {

        return new Promise(resolve => {

            this.http.get('http://localhost:54037/api/home')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    }
```

**And in Component:**

```
this.s.GetHttpData()
        .then(data => { 
             console.log("Http call  completed: "+data);
});
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled